# How to get the child div id's,which are directly the child under one parent div?

Tags: java, html, css, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

If I have a markup like shown below,i want to access each of the eigth div seperately from its parent div and print its id using for loop.

```html
<div class=abc>
  <div id="parent">
    <div id="one">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="two">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="three">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="four">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="five">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="six">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="seven">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
    <div id="eight">
       <div id=........</div>
       <div id=........</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But while I am printing(in Java), every div id 's under each of eight div's are also printing.How to get only the id's of each eight div's in one for-loop?
I am Automating a website using selenium Web Driver. I tried like this:

```
List<WebElement> eightdivs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#abc div:nth-child(n)"));
     for(WebElement eachdiv : eightdivs)
      {
         System.out.println(eachdiv.getAttribute("id"));
      }
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript? They are not the same language.. Other that both having Java in the name, they have nothing in common.

Comment: did you meant javascript?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Is this really Java, or is it JavaScript? If it's Java, what library are you using to handle the HTML, if any?

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is why you need to show us what you've tried in code *when first posting your question*.

Answer (score 1):

The selector:

```
#abc div:nth-child(n)
```

Selects all `div` elements that are the nth child of their parent, within `#abc`. The space is a descendant selector which means the parent can either be `#abc` or anything inside it. This means *all* your `div`s should be selected because they're all the nth children of their parents (although your parent element is either `.abc` or `#parent`, but not `#abc`, so the selector you used would actually return *nothing* at all).

You should change `#abc` to `#parent`, use the child selector `>` for children directly under `#parent`, and remove the `:nth-child(n)` part because it's redundant:

```
List<WebElement> eightdivs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#parent > div"));

for (WebElement eachdiv : eightdivs)
{
    System.out.println(eachdiv.getAttribute("id"));
}
```